# DCOM Security Settings not exported with secedit

Tags: windows, user-management, user-permissions, dcom, com

I've got a problem with exporting the DCOM-settings.
I call

`secedit /export /cfg C:\UserAccess\config.txt`

This should export the COM and DCOM settings.
But I don't get all of the settings.
For example Act as a part of the operatingsystem (SeTcbPrivilege) is missing.
And, and thats my biggest problem, the DCOM-settings

- MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DCOM\MachineAccessRestriction
- MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
  NT\DCOM\MachineLaunchRestriction

are missing.
But DCOM is enabled.
Do you have any idea why they are not exported ?